# How to get all post_parents of a post?

Tags: posts, query

Unfortunately, $post->post_parent is a single variable and not an array. I want to get all post_parents of a post (especially of an attachment, which is often linked to multiple posts!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Ravs solution I worked this out. This function returns *all* parent posts, and it checks all attachments attached to all posts.

See this: http://codepad.org/GmNh7M9e

Answer (score 1):

You clearly refer to [this function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors) which is used like this :

```
global $post;
$parents = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
```

Comment: Looks good. I tried this out but why does it output only "Array"? The attachment got multiple ancestors of course.

$attachment = get_post($file_id);
echo get_post_ancestors( $attachment );

Comment: there are multiple values to return

Comment: But they aren't showing up, the array is empty.

Comment: Means there are no ancestor. You need to target attachments in this case. So you can use a `get_posts()` to get only attachments and then retrieve ancestors.

Comment: why can't i use a specific "post"/attachment like in my example?

Comment: you can, it is based on post ID so in your case attachment ID.

Comment: but isn't this what i did? my attachment id is stored in $file_id. maybe i am blind, i am sorry! but i don't get why this doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

This function gives the list of post ids to which attachment attach.

Paste this code in `functions.php`

```
/**
 * get_attachment_parent fx gives array of post id to which given attachment attach
 * @param  [int $att_id attachment id
 * @return array        list of post ids
 */
function ravs_get_attachment_parent( $att_id ){

    $args=array(
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        );

    $posts=get_posts($args);

    if( ! $posts && empty($posts) )
            return array();

    $ancestors = array();

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $attachment = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
        if( $att_id === $attachment  && ! in_array($post->ID, $ancestors))
            $ancestors[] = $post->ID;
    }
    return $ancestors;
}
```

and access this function in loop

```
if( has_post_thumbnail() )
 print_r( ravs_get_attachment_parent( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID())) );
```

or outside loop

```
print_r( ravs_get_attachment_parent( $attachment_id );
```

Comment: thanks this helped me a lot :-)
i adapted it so it can now handle with attachments which are attached to multiple posts but also with multiple attachments attached to one post. 
see this: http://codepad.org/GmNh7M9e